# PHP MySQLi to HTML combobox

Tags: php, html, mysqli, combobox

I'm trying to pass data from a MySQL database to a HTML combobox and i'm using php to do that

```
<form method="POST">
     <select class="js_inline_input">
          <?php
               $servername = "localhost";
               $username = "root";
               $password = "";
               $db = "js_milhoes";

               $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

               if ($conn->connect_error) {
                  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
               }else{
                  echo "<option> Connected successfully </option>";
               } 

               $sql = "SELECT * FROM js_country";
               $result = $conn->query($sql);

               while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
               //My Personal echo     
              echo "<option value='".$row['countryCode']."'>".$row['countryName']."</option>";
              //Echo i saw on this site
              echo "<option value='{$row->countryCode}'>{$row->countryName}</option>";
               }

               $conn->close();

            ?>
      </select>
    </form>
```

It should list all the countries in the combobox but what displays is:
   - From first echo: ".$row['countryName']."
   - From second echo: {$row->countryCode}

I already check the connection, and before i add a if that says that the query is not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was a stupid problem, when i changed from wamp 2.5 to wamp 3 i forget to delete the wwamp paste and i had 2, so i has using the wrong fill and because that one wasn't in a server with apache the browser comments the php

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your second `<option>` isn't showing is because you are using a "fetch object" syntax `$row->column`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

You need to use one or the other; not both.

Either you use

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo "<option value='".$row['countryCode']."'>".$row['countryName']."</option>";

}
```

or (and escaping with double-quotes):

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($result)){

    echo "<option value=\"{$row->countryCode}\">{$row->countryCode}</option>";

}
```

---

You also need to note that column names are case-sensitive when iterating over those like that.

Meaning that, `countryCode` and `countrycode` are two different animals here, as is `countryName` and `countryname`; should it be the case.

- Check for errors on your query.

---

**Footnotes:**

You state: *"but what displays is: - From first echo: ".$row['countryName']." - From second echo: {$row->countryCode}"*

I don't understand what you mean by that. I've tested your code and it works fine *(besides the "fetch object" syntax issue)*. If what you mean by that is you are seeing "code" rather than being parsed, then you are either  not using a webserver, or that you are accessing it as `file:///file.php` rather than `http://localhost/file.php` or as `.html` should this be the case as the file extension is unknown.

- That is my conclusion for this question.

Comment: i inspected my code and part of the php is commented and i don't know why

Comment: @JSoares Ok so where are we with the question? What I posted in relation to what you posted for code should have solved it. I don't post answers that don't work, which I did test before posting.